# Why does my code never enter my while loop?

Tags: c#, while-loop

I'm working on a quiz program.

The code below is in the `Form2_Load` method.

`ctr` and `que[]` are global `integer` variables.

Can you please help me work out why the code doesn't enter the `while(read.Read())` loop?

```
con.Open();
com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM questions";
OleDbDataReader read = com.ExecuteReader();

while (read.Read()) { // this is the loop I'm talking about
    if (int.Parse(read["qid1"].ToString()) == que[ctr]) { // where que[] is containing of 30 unique random numbers
        qtnTxt.Text = read["qtn"].ToString(); //For output of the question
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) { //for unique random choices in quiz bee. I have no problem about this.
            ans[x] = ran.Next(2, 6);
            for (int y = x; y >= 0; y--) {
                if (x == y) {
                    continue;
                } else if (ans[x] == ans[y]) {
                    ans[x] = ran.Next(2, 6);
                    y = x;
                }
            }
        }
    //Choices outputs
    aBtn.Text = read.GetString(ans[0]).ToString();
    bBtn.Text = read.GetString(ans[1]).ToString();
    cBtn.Text = read.GetString(ans[2]).ToString();
    dBtn.Text = read.GetString(ans[3]).ToString();
    }
}
ctr++;

read.Close();
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Because `reader.Read()` is returning `false`?

Comment: Why does it return `false`?

Comment: Because the query is not returning any results. I have no idea why that  would be happening because there is no relevant information to diagnose any further.

Comment: Are you sure it's not entering the while loop? Maybe it is, but the if statement on the next line is always false?

Comment: I have the same code in other method and its working... it should work then. The codes are identical, copied and pasted.

Comment: Please check the output given by reader.Read() and int.Parse(read["qid1"].ToString()) == que[ctr]   If you still have something you do not understand, please post the said output

Answer (score -1, accepted):

move `com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM questions";` below `OleDbDataReader read = com.ExecuteReader();`

and there's the answer. I just tried it on some apps i made and this is my conclusion.

Comment: But this is wrong. Opening the reader and only then setting the SQL to use is surely incorrect. If this is the answer to the question then I propose closing and deleting the whole question as this is *way* too localized to benefit anyone else. There must be bugs present in the code that isn't shown.